# Bash if statement using wmctrl and xdotool

Tags: arrays, bash

What I'm trying to accomplish:

- Making an array of active opened windows
- uses a combination of wmctrl & xdotool
- if the window focus changes then I add that window to the top of the
  array
- then delete the duplicate window in position [>=1] in the
  array.

My problem is that I cannot seem to correctly deal with checking between the wmctrl window id that is open and the xdotool focus window (one is an integer and one is a hexdecimal). My if statement needs work, but I am having a problem finding out how to correctly check my xdotool window data against my array containing wmcrtl window id data.

- `fid` = focus window id
- `appArray` contains `wmctrl` window id's in an array.

```
echo -e "-------Current array of active windows-----"
for i in ${appArray[@]}; do echo $i; done

while :
do
    #UPDATES CURRENT WINDOW FOCUS
    fid=$(xdotool getactivewindow)

    #CHECK IF WINDOW OF FOCUS IS AT TOP OF THE ARRAY
    if [ $appArray == $(printf 0x0%x $fid) ] ;

    #IF IT IS THEN DO NOTHING
    then
        echo -e "----current window is at top of array, and active------"

    else
    #IF IT ISNT THEN UPDATE ARRAY
        echo -e "\n------Adding new focus window to top of array------"
        appArray=($(printf 0x0%x $fid) "${appArray[@]}");

        #find location of duplicate if any
        newArray=$(echo "${appArray[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ' ')

        appArray=("${newArray[@]}")
        #prints the array of applications
        for i in ${appArray[@]}; do echo $i; done
        echo "----------------------------------------------------"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to shift each window in the array down one position until you find the target.

```
target="$(printf '0x0%x' "$fid")"
prev="$target"
# Loop over array indices
for i in "${!appArray[@]}"; do
    curr="${appArray[$i]}"
    appArray[$i]="$prev"
    prev="$curr"
    if [ "$curr" = "$target" ]; then
        break
    fi
done
```

Another way is to loop over the indices to find the index of the target, and use that to update the array.

```
target="$(printf '0x0%x' "$fid")"
for i in "${!appArray[@]}"; do
    if [ "${appArray[$i]}" = "$target" ]; then
        unset appArray[$i]
        break
    fi
done
appArray=("$target" "${appArray[@]}")
```